# Can I color different layers with the same pseudocolor color map?

Tags: qgis

I have multiple DEM layers in my map (downloaded from atlas.louisiana.gov/lidar), but I cannot seem to get the colors to line up.  You can see in the attached image that the colors are not continuous between the layers, but they should be.  (I've checked the values, and they are).  I've tried several ways around this, but none of them seem to work.  This data is rendered as Single Band Gray.

1)  right clicking on one layer, selecting copy style, and then pasting it into the other layer.

2)  saving the style from one layer and loading it into the other.

3)  changing the color map to grayscle, inputting min and max, and then reverting back to pseudocolor.  (that one seemed silly)

It seems like the problem is that I can only do a pseudocolor with standard deviations, and not min/max values.  Is that correct?  There seems like there should be some way around that...

Any ideas?

Comment: the image wouldn't attach....but all that matters is that the colormaps aren't continuous between the two tiles

Comment: You can either build a virtual raster catalog or merge the dems. Both options are under raster/miscellaneous. I personally prefer merging the dems, but is worth to try both procedures. After merging or build the virtual catalog you can try the pseudocolor map. Hope it helps.

Comment: Gerardo thanks.  Something went wrong with the merge, but building the virtual catalog worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you use arcgis 
1. create one DEM with with colors with symbology example grey color with continuous values
2. Then right click on other layers (DEMs) go to properties ----- symbology -----click import ---- and select the first DEM you colour coded first
3. If u do this for all layers you will get consistent maps where you can compare all DEMS